# what should be the Hadoop cofigurations to be used for 100 gb of csv files for analysis in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have around 100 GB of data in CSV format on which I intend to do some transformation like aggregation, data splitting and after that do some clustering using ML package of Apache Spark.

I have tried it by uploading data on MYSQ trying to automate the process on python but it's taking too much time to build any solution.

What is the configuration  I need to setup and how I should start with the spark?

I am new in spark. I am planning to use cloud services.

Comment: Which cloud services? If you upload your files there, the size of the data doesn't matter. You will need at least 100GB of available memory to process the entire file. If you want to use HDFS, you'll need to have at least 400GB of disk space as the file is replicated 3 times, and you need overhead for extra data

Answer (score 2):

1. I'm going to recommend you learn to use spark locally with a small subset of the data; you can run it standalone with a few tens moving to hundreds of MB. Its limited, but you can learn the tooling without paying. Your first spark dataframe query could be sampling the source data and saving it into a more efficient query format.
2. CSV isn't a great format for big data; Spark likes Parquet and for 2.3+ ORC). Embrace them for better perf.
3. Play with "notebooks"; Apache Zeppelin is one you can install and run locally.

Like I say, learn to play with small amounts. Spark is very interactive & working with small datasets is an easy way to learn fast.

Comment: I would love to do that but right now I am in the middle of a project with lots of csv file provided by the client. My solution on mysql taking lots of time, therefore, the need to scale it up.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do that but it depends on your case. As far as I know, HDFS with default configuration(without any specific tuning) works fine. Majority of Hadoop tuning guides are focused on YARN side. So, let me make a plan like below:

Generally speaking, you can put your (raw) data in HDFS and load them in Apache Spark and save them in Parquet/ORC like below:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField,StringType
myschema = StructType([StructField("FirstName",StringType(),True),StructField("LastName",StringType(),True)])
mydf = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header","true").schema(myschema).option("delimiter",",").load("hdfs://hadoopmaster:9000/user/hduser/mydata.csv")
mydf.count()
mydf.repartition(6).write.format("parquet").save("hdfs://hadoopmaster:9000/user/hduser/DataInParquet")

newdf = spark.read.parquet("hdfs://hadoopmaster:9000/user/hduser/DataInParquet")
newdf.count()
```

Finally, compare `mydf.count()` with `newdf.count()`. That will run faster than raw format. In addition, your data size will decrease from 100GB to ~24GB.

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to hadoop, spark and interested to setup hadoop environment in cloud. I would suggest you to go with Elastic Map Reduce(EMR) powered by AWS. You can create On demand spark cluster with the user defined configuration to process a wide range of data sets.

https://aws.amazon.com/emr/

https://aws.amazon.com/emr/details/spark/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-launch.html

Or

You can setup a hadoop cluster on top of EC2 instance or in any cloud platform with the required number of nodes with sufficient RAM and CPU. Storage optimized instances is preferred over here to analyze a large data set.

We do not need to bother about storage cost, For storage optimized instances, AWS offers free ephemeral storage data disk with size 1 - 2TB depends on instance size.

Note: Data in the ephemeral storage will be lost when the VM is rebooted. We can persist the processed data in S3 at the cheapest cost.

**When it comes to cluster configuration, the list of things to be checked.**

- Spark on YARN is preferred
- Set minimum and maximum core and memory in yarn node manager container settings for your spark executors.
- Enable dynamic memory allocation in spark
- Set container size to the maximum and spark memory fraction to maximum to avoid shuffling multiple times and frequent spilling and cached data eviction.
- Use kryo serialization to get high performance.
- Enable compression for map outputs before shuffling.
- Enable spark web UI to track your application tasks and its stages.

Apache Spark Config Reference: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/configuration.html